# How to translate automatic site with browser language or user ip address in gtranslate plugin in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, translate

I want to do automatic translation of my site/pages with default browser language or user IP address. I am using gtranslate plugin in my site. Any help or suggestion should me useful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In gtranslate plugin there is checkbox Auto switch to browser language:. You can check it and try it. It will work.

Comment: Is there any way that i can translate site in other language based on user's ip address?